# How to close browser after runnning all tests in testng suite with selenium

Tags: java, selenium, testng

I have a `TESTNG` file like below: Where tests in `credentials` and `checkHome` are executed first before runnning `DatacheckTest`.

*DatacheckTest.xml*

```xml
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "https://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
    <suite name="Suite">
        <suite-files>
            <suite-file
                path="./credentials.xml"></suite-file>
            <suite-file path="./checkHome.xml"></suite-file>
        </suite-files>
    
        <test thread-count="5" name="Test">
            <classes>
                <class name="DatacheckTest" />
            </classes>
        </test> <!-- Test -->
    </suite> <!-- Suite -->
```

All the `Testng` class file below extend `Base` which gets driver information. I want to close the browser session after running all the tests in the suite.
for example when I run `DatacheckTest`, the `Base` class `afterSuite` methhod annotated with `AfterSuite` , closes browser and ends the session soon after running `credentials.xml`.

1. How can I make the browser close after running all tests in the suite.
2. When we are running multiple suites, close browser after everything is finished.

```java
public class Credentials extends Base {
    @Test
    void test1() {
    }
}

public class CheckHome extends Base {
    @Test
    void test2() {
    }
}

public class DatacheckTest extends Base {
    @Test
    void test3() {
    }
}

public class Base extends {
    @AfterSuite
    public void afterSuite() {
        driver.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: @Yang, it is just a typo

Comment: please check my edit.

Answer (score 1):

`@AfterSuite` will not work for you, since you refer to multiple suite files and this will be invoked multiple times.

**IExecutionListener in TestNG**

The `IExecutionListener` listener monitors the start and the end of the whole TestNG execution process.

It's the most generic listener, which allows executing some code *before everything* and *after everything*.

The `IExecutionListener` contains two methods:

- `onExecutionStart`
- `onExecutionFinish`

You have to implement a custom ExecutionListener.

```
import org.testng.IExecutionListener

class ExecutionListener implements IExecutionListener {

    @Override
    public void onExecutionStart() {
        // launch driver
        System.out.println("onExecutionStart invoked");
    }

    @Override
    public void onExecutionFinish() {
        // close driver
        System.out.println("onExecutionFinish invoked");
    }
}
```

and apply it on Base class:

```
import org.testng.annotations.Listeners

@Listeners(ExecutionListener.class)
class Base {
    // some implementation
}
```